# Kafka - How to define user and password in springboot yml file?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, sasl

I have installed kafka and define the user and password as SASL_PLAINTEXT protocol, I made some example in the console and I can send messages to the topic and receive those messages using their respective credentials, now I need to replicate that configuration in my spring boot application,

This is my application.yml file:

```
server:
  port: 65498
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ip:9092
    properties:
      security:
        protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      sasl:
        mechanism: PLAIN
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin-secret";
    producer:
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

The application starts well but when I try to send a message it throws the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

One thing I notice is if I don't pass the producer.properties to the producer in the console it throws a similarly error:

```
WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Can someone help me with this issue?,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this thread can give you some hints https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/606

Comment: In fact I already seen that issue and follow the same configuration and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, my error was that on my server.properties in kafka I defined the `advertised.listeners` as `SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092` so my clients tryed to connect using localhost so I changed the localhost to the host ip and it works!